# Failed to instantiate com.android.menubar.internal.MenuBarEnhancerCocoa:

Tags: android, eclipse, cocoa

I've been trying for an hour to resolve this. There's one item on Stack Overflow under this subject, but not any real help. I have a new install of the Android SDK, with Eclipse, all current as of this date, with all SDK items installed dating back to v 2.2, all tools, all extras, etc. I'm on a Mac, 10.6.8. Was hoping to begin my first project but can't get past the initial activation of the SDK manager. Despite everything I've attempted as a fix, I'm continuing to get this error in the console:

> Failed to instantiate com.android.menubar.internal.MenuBarEnhancerCocoa: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.menubar.internal.MenuBarEnhancerCocoa.

If anyone has any suggestions on a remedy, I'd greatly appreciate a hand.

Comment: Seems like you are missing a jar.

Comment: Check this link..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257732/failed-to-instantiate-com-android-menubar-internal-menubarenhancercocoa